# Wrong MBR in NTFS partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have a inacessible partition. By inaccesible I mean it cannot be accesed from Windows command prompt ("file or directory is damaged and not readable"). Even chkdsk could not do anything: "Could not recognise version and state of the partition. CHKDSK has terminated."

I tried testdisk with the following log:

```
Partition table type (auto): Intel
Disk \\.\PhysicalDrive1 - 500 GB / 465 GiB
Partition table type: Intel

Interface Advanced
Geometry from i386 MBR: head=255 sector=63
BAD_RS LBA=1979 411648
check_part_i386 1 type 12: no test
NTFS at 55064/125/38
check_part_i386 3 type 12: no test
 1 P Compaq Diagnostics       0  31 27 55064 125 37  884609093
 2 P HPFS - NTFS          55064 125 38 58888 243 43   61440000
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 31 GB / 29 GiB
 3 P Compaq Diagnostics   58888 243 44 60801  47 46   30720000
```

I am interested in the first partition. After changing it to NTFS:

```
ntfs_boot_sector
 1 P HPFS - NTFS              0  31 27 55064 125 37  884609093
NTFS at 0/31/27
NTFS at 0/31/27
Error: size boot_sector 946728368 > partition 884609093
filesystem size           884609093 946728368
sectors_per_cluster       8 8
mft_lcn                   786432 786432
mftmirr_lcn               22435414 2
clusters_per_mft_record   -10 -10
clusters_per_index_record 1 1
Boot sector
Status: OK

Backup boot sector
Error: size boot_sector 946728368 > partition 884609093
Status: Bad

Sectors are not identical.

A valid NTFS Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.
$MFT has invalid magic.
ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error.
$MFT has invalid magic.
ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
$MFT has invalid magic.
ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error.
$MFT has invalid magic.
ntfs_mft_load(): Failed.
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error.
Not an exFAT boot sector.

 1 P HPFS - NTFS              0  31 27 55064 125 37  884609093
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
```

And when I dump the MFS and its backup, I get:

```
Boot sector                        Backup boot sector
0000 eb52904e 54465320   .R.NTFS   eb52904e 54465320   .R.NTFS 
0008 20202000 02080000      .....  20202000 02080000      .....
0010 00000000 00f80000   ........  00000000 00f80000   ........
0018 3f00ff00 bb070000   ?.......  3f00ff00 00480600   ?....H..
0020 00000000 80000000   ........  00000000 80008000   ........
0028 4410ba34 00000000   D..4....  afed6d38 00000000   ..m8....
0030 00000c00 00000000   ........  00000c00 00000000   ........
0038 56565601 00000000   VVV.....  02000000 00000000   ........
0040 f6000000 01000000   ........  f6000000 01000000   ........
0048 01020304 05060708   ........  d2dbc960 dfc96080   ...`..`.
0050 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 fa33c08e   .....3..
0058 00000000 00000000   ........  d0bc007c fb68c007   ...|.h..
0060 00000000 00000000   ........  1f1e6866 00cb8816   ..hf....
0068 00000000 00000000   ........  0e006681 3e03004e   ..f.>..N
0070 00000000 00000000   ........  54465375 15b441bb   TFSu..A.
0078 00000000 00000000   ........  aa55cd13 720c81fb   .U..r...
0080 00000000 00000000   ........  55aa7506 f7c10100   U.u.....
0088 00000000 00000000   ........  7503e9dd 001e83ec   u.......
0090 00000000 00000000   ........  18681a00 b4488a16   .h...H..
0098 00000000 00000000   ........  0e008bf4 161fcd13   ........
00A0 00000000 00000000   ........  9f83c418 9e581f72   .....X.r
00A8 00000000 00000000   ........  e13b060b 0075dba3   .;...u..
00B0 00000000 00000000   ........  0f00c12e 0f00041e   ........
00B8 00000000 00000000   ........  5a33dbb9 00202bc8   Z3... +.
00C0 00000000 00000000   ........  66ff0611 0003160f   f.......
00C8 00000000 00000000   ........  008ec2ff 061600e8   ........
00D0 00000000 00000000   ........  4b002bc8 77efb800   K.+.w...
00D8 00000000 00000000   ........  bbcd1a66 23c0752d   ...f#.u-
00E0 00000000 00000000   ........  6681fb54 43504175   f..TCPAu
00E8 00000000 00000000   ........  2481f902 01721e16   $....r..
00F0 00000000 00000000   ........  6807bb16 68700e16   h...hp..
00F8 00000000 00000000   ........  68090066 53665366   h..fSfSf
0100 00000000 00000000   ........  55161616 68b80166   U...h..f
0108 00000000 00000000   ........  610e07cd 1a33c0bf   a....3..
0110 00000000 00000000   ........  2810b9d8 0ffcf3aa   (.......
0118 00000000 00000000   ........  e95f0190 9066601e   ._...f`.
0120 00000000 00000000   ........  0666a111 00660306   .f...f..
0128 00000000 00000000   ........  1c001e66 68000000   ...fh...
0130 00000000 00000000   ........  00665006 53680100   .fP.Sh..
0138 00000000 00000000   ........  681000b4 428a160e   h...B...
0140 00000000 00000000   ........  00161f8b f4cd1366   .......f
0148 00000000 00000000   ........  595b5a66 5966591f   Y[ZfYfY.
0150 00000000 00000000   ........  0f821600 66ff0611   ....f...
0158 00000000 00000000   ........  0003160f 008ec2ff   ........
0160 00000000 00000000   ........  0e160075 bc071f66   ...u...f
0168 00000000 00000000   ........  61c3a0f8 01e80900   a.......
0170 00000000 00000000   ........  a0fb01e8 0300f4eb   ........
0178 00000000 00000000   ........  fdb4018b f0ac3c00   ......<.
0180 00000000 00000000   ........  7409b40e bb0700cd   t.......
0188 00000000 00000000   ........  10ebf2c3 0d0a4120   ......A 
0190 00000000 00000000   ........  6469736b 20726561   disk rea
0198 00000000 00000000   ........  64206572 726f7220   d error 
01A0 00000000 00000000   ........  6f636375 72726564   occurred
01A8 00000000 00000000   ........  000d0a42 4f4f544d   ...BOOTM
01B0 00000000 00000000   ........  47522069 73206d69   GR is mi
01B8 00000000 00000000   ........  7373696e 67000d0a   ssing...
01C0 00000000 00000000   ........  424f4f54 4d475220   BOOTMGR 
01C8 00000000 00000000   ........  69732063 6f6d7072   is compr
01D0 00000000 00000000   ........  65737365 64000d0a   essed...
01D8 00000000 00000000   ........  50726573 73204374   Press Ct
01E0 00000000 00000000   ........  726c2b41 6c742b44   rl+Alt+D
01E8 00000000 00000000   ........  656c2074 6f207265   el to re
01F0 00000000 00000000   ........  73746172 740d0a00   start...
01F8 00000000 000055aa   ......U.  8ca9bed6 000055aa   ......U.
```

I am not guru enough to see what is wrong. Could someone help me to possibly recover the partition and save the data?

EDIT: I also tried `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` before testdisk, both operations successfully completed, but I don't think it recognized the partition as a system one. In `diskpart` I see the partition as RAW.

Comment: It may be too late now after you changed the partition type to NTFS and chkdsk'd, but the original partition looks like a type 0x12 'Compaq Diagnostics' which you could have made accessible by simply unhiding it and setting the type to (most likely) FAT32.

Comment: @dvix Thank you for your comment, but I am 100% sure the partition was NTFS before. Even the NTFS headers look kinda "correct". I don't think I wrote anything to the disk - CHKDSK could not read anything and testdisk was in readonly mode.